# Как убрать ошибку связанную ограничением внешним ключом

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Делаю insert в таблицу. Появляется такая ошибка.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_METHODTESTS_TESTID". The conflict occurred in database "Solution21", table "dbo.TESTNAME", column 'TESTID'.
The statement has been terminated."
```

Сама таблица, куда я пытаюсь вставить данные выглядит так.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[METHODTESTS] (
    [OID]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [TESTTYPID]             SMALLINT       NULL,
    [TESTID]                SMALLINT       NULL,
    [METHODID]              SMALLINT       NULL,
    [TESTTYPEID]            SMALLINT       NULL,
    [SORTNR]                INT            DEFAULT ((10)) NULL,
    [GROUPDESCRIPTION]      NVARCHAR (512) NULL,
    [SHORTGROUPDESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR (512) NULL,
    [TESTTYPE111]           SMALLINT       NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField]   INT            NULL,
    [GCRecord]              INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_METHODTESTS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_METHODTESTS_TESTID] FOREIGN KEY ([TESTID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TESTNAME] ([TESTID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_METHODTESTS_METHODID] FOREIGN KEY ([METHODID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[METHODNAME] ([METHODID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_METHODTESTS_TESTTYPEID] FOREIGN KEY ([TESTTYPEID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TESTTYPES] ([TESTTYPEID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_METHODTESTS_TESTTYPE111] FOREIGN KEY ([TESTTYPE111]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TESTTYPES] ([TESTTYPEID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [I_MT_METHODTESTID]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([METHODID] ASC, [TESTID] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iGCRecord_METHODTESTS]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([GCRecord] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iTESTID_METHODTESTS]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([TESTID] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iMETHODID_METHODTESTS]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([METHODID] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iTESTTYPEID_METHODTESTS]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([TESTTYPEID] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iTESTTYPE111_METHODTESTS]
    ON [dbo].[METHODTESTS]([TESTTYPE111] ASC);
```

А вот сама таблица, где происходит ошибка.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTNAME] (
    [TESTID]           SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION]      NVARCHAR (250)  NULL,
    [SHORTNAME]        NVARCHAR (250)  NULL,
    [SHORTDESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    [TESTTYPE]         SMALLINT        NULL,
    [TESTTYPEID]       SMALLINT        NULL,
    [TESTTYPE111]      SMALLINT        NULL,
    [Methodname]       SMALLINT        NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TESTNAME] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TESTID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TESTNAME_TESTTYPE] FOREIGN KEY ([TESTTYPE]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TESTTYPES] ([TESTTYPEID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TESTNAME_TESTTYPE111] FOREIGN KEY ([TESTTYPE111]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TESTTYPES] ([TESTTYPEID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TESTNAME_Methodname] FOREIGN KEY ([Methodname]) REFERENCES [dbo].[METHODNAME] ([METHODID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [I_TESTSHORT]
    ON [dbo].[TESTNAME]([SHORTNAME] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iTESTTYPE_TESTNAME]
    ON [dbo].[TESTNAME]([TESTTYPE] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iTESTTYPE111_TESTNAME]
    ON [dbo].[TESTNAME]([TESTTYPE111] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iMethodname_TESTNAME]
    ON [dbo].[TESTNAME]([Methodname] ASC);
```

Вот код с insert запросом.

```
 METHODTESTS objMETHODTESTS = new METHODTESTS(objs.Session);

                foreach (var VARIABLE in methodtests)
                {
                    String[] words = VARIABLE.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    var a = objMETHODTESTS.TESTTYPEID = gs.ToTESTTYPES(words[2], objs.Session);
                    var b = objMETHODTESTS.TESTID = gs.ToTESTNAME(words[1], objs.Session);
                    var c = objMETHODTESTS.METHODID = gs.ToMETHODNAME(words[0], objs.Session);
                    var d = objMETHODTESTS.SORTNR = Convert.ToInt32(words[3]);
                    var e1 = objMETHODTESTS.GROUPDESCRIPTION = words[4];
                    var f1 = objMETHODTESTS.SHORTGROUPDESCRIPTION = words[5];

                    SqlCommand command6 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO METHODTESTS (TESTTYPEID, TESTID, METHODID,SORTNR,GROUPDESCRIPTION,SHORTGROUPDESCRIPTION) VALUES (@a, @b,@c,@d,@e1,@f1)", connection);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a.TESTTYPEID);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b.TESTID);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c.METHODID);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", d);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e1", e1);
                    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", f1.ToString());
                    command6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Я понимаю, что стоит ограничение связанное с внешним ключом, но сами таблицы  генерированны ОРМ. И С какой стороны подступиться к этой проблеме чтобы ее исправить увы из-за небольшого опыта мне не ясно.

Метод выполняющий конвертацию.

```
 public  TESTNAME ToTESTNAME(string v,Session session)
        {
            var @implicit = new TESTNAME(session);
            @implicit.TESTID = Convert.ToInt16(v);
            return @implicit;
        }
```

Нужен он, так как без него не получается ибо  words[1] это string потому приходится конвертировать.

Comment: Либо следить за порядком в последовательности Insert, чтобы первыми добавлялись "родительские записи", либо снести констрэйт, сделать insert, удалить все записи, в которых нарушена ссылочная целостность, вернуть констрэйнт.

Comment: `gs.ToTESTNAME(words[1], objs.Session)` должен вернуть `TESTID`, который существует в `[dbo].[TESTNAME]`, но этого не происходит, разбирайтесь почему.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Спасибо за ответ, dbo].[TESTNAME] это сделал маппинг ОРМ, и это связь.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Вы имеете ввиду под родительскими поля с внешними ключами?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, не важно кто сделал таблицы. Проверьте что в массиве `words`, что выполняет метод `gs.ToTESTNAME`. Вообще по коду: не понятно зачем объявлена переменная `objMETHODTESTS` - она не используется; использование Parameters.AddWithValue - плохая практика, предпочтительно использовать методы, в которые явно передается тип и размер переменной.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin добавил в вопрос сам метод ToTESTNAME, а переменная  objMETHODTESTS нужна чтобы я смог достать то что внутри класса METHODTESTS

Comment: Ну вот, метод `gs.ToTESTNAME(words[1], objs.Session)` возвращает значение типа `TESTNAME`, у которого есть поле `TESTID`, скорее всего должно быть как-то так: `var b = objMETHODTESTS.TESTID = gs.ToTESTNAME(words[1], objs.Session).TESTID;`

Comment: `var b = objMETHODTESTS.TESTID = gs.ToTESTNAME(words[1], objs.Session);` почему вы в `TESTID` пишете `TESTNAME`?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ, потому, что в классе METHODTESTS  свойство TESTID имеет тип TESTNAME этот класс сгенерирован автоматически орм, и в орм настроены все связи, которые корректно работают.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Попробовал ваш вариант. Ошибка осталось

Comment: ну значит смотрите, какие значения вы посылаете здесь `command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b.TESTID);` и все ли они соответвуют записям в таблице `[dbo].[TESTNAME]`

Comment: @tym32167 получается, что отладчик показывает что  b.TESTID = 965, далее смотрю в таблице [dbo].[TESTNAME] и вижу, что такого значения нет. Получается, где то что то перепуталось.

Comment: Именно об этом и говорит ваша ошибка в вопросе, `INSERT` не может добавить значение 965, потому что такого `TESTID` нет в таблице `[dbo].[TESTNAME]`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за подсказку, буду перепроверять исходные данные.